# Is there a way to find the 2 whole factors of an int that are closest together?

Tags: c, function, int

I'm a beginner still learning to us C and I don't know how to find the factors of an int that are the closest to each other.

For example, if the input was the number 6, the output would be [2,3]. If the input was 24, then the output would be [4,6].

Is there a way to do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: they're the closest factors to the square root of your number.

Comment: Are you sure? For example for the number 1111 = 11 * 101, the two factors closest together are 1 and 11.

Comment: If the input is 24, then the output should be [1,2], or [2,3], or [3,4].

Answer (score 11):

The algorithm to do this is simple; take the square root of your number as an integer (you want to truncate, not round). Test if that value is a factor of your input; if so, your input divided by that number are your answer. Otherwise, subtract 1 from your previous value and try again.

In code (the array literal is the wrong syntax, but the theory is correct):

```
//this code assumes that your input is > 0, will not work otherwise
function int[] getClosestFactors(int input) {
  int testNum = (int)sqrt(input);
  while (input % testNum != 0) {
    testNum--;
  }
  return {testNum, input / testNum};
}
```

Basically, you know that in any pair of factors, the lowest factor must be less than or equal to the square root. So if you start at the integer equal to or less than the square root of your input, and count down, the first factor you find will be the smaller of the pair of closest factors. This terminates for all integers > 0 because you will eventually reach 1, which is a factor of all other numbers.

Comment: This will take a bit in the case of 18446744073709551566... Which happens to be 2 * 9223372036854775783, both of which are prime. Still, I guess it'd only be about 4294967296 iterations, so not too horribly bad... Of course, the other alternative implementation I can think of off the top of my head would require fully factoring the number first, so it probably wouldn't fare too much better for efficiency...

Comment: For that number, surely 1 and 2 are the two factors closest together.

Comment: @gnasher729 I would presume (possibly incorrectly) that 1 should not be a valid candidate, except possibly in the case of a prime number. Otherwise, "1 and 2" would be a trivial answer for any even number that didn't also happen to be a perfect square... Yet another way in which the question is a bit under-specified, as you've already noted in a couple other ways...

Comment: @twalberg In order to fully optimize the algorithm, we'd need more knowledge of the expected distribution of inputs. Factoring can't possibly be faster without implementing a much more complex algorithm (and likely not then); my algorithm is effectively just a textbook factoring algorithm that short-circuits on the first factor it finds.

Comment: @gnasher729 while the op was not perfectly clear, her examples implied that she intended to ask for the "factor pair" with the smallest difference, rather than any two factors at all. This small clarification would fully specify the intended question, while also guaranteeing uniqueness and aligning with the examples given by the op. I think I've answered the question the op intended to ask, even though I admit I am making an assumption about her motives.