# Reshape object with shape (500,)

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

I am using the following code to reshape an object with shape (625,):

```
u1 = np.linspace(16, 20, 25)
u2 = np.linspace(16, 20, 25)
u1, u2 = np.meshgrid(u1, u2)
U = np.vstack((u1.flatten(), u2.flatten()))
Z = Z.reshape(u1.shape)
```

The result is a shape of (25,25)

Now, my question is: How can I reshape an object with shape `(500,)`?

- Of course, an array of size 500 cannot be reshaped into shape `(25,25)`
- Using

```
u1 = np.linspace(16, 20, math.sqrt(500))
```

won't work as `np.linspace` needs integers for the number of samples

Could you help`?

Comment: what shape do you want?  Its product has to be 500

Comment: Ideally sqrt(500) * sqrt(500). Is it possible?

Comment: You can't reshape to fractional values.  The reshaped array has to have an integer number of rows and and integer number of columns.  It can't have 24.34 rows!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to get as close to a square matrix as possible. This is equivalent to the problem of finding two whole factors of `n`: `p, q`, such that `p * q == n` and `p` as close as possible to `sqrt(n)`.

That question is not new. For example, it has been posed on Math StackExchange [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24437/how-would-i-find-the-factor-of-x-nearest-to-sqrtx), where it is established that there is no "quick way" of doing this (e.g. see [this fantastic comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24437/how-would-i-find-the-factor-of-x-nearest-to-sqrtx#comment52720_24437) or the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/24500/71963)'s argument about this being the strength of RSA).

On StackOverflow, there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28328437/758174).

**Edit** this is less subtle but faster (at least for small enough `n`):

```py
def np_squarishrt(n):
    a = np.arange(1, isqrt(n), dtype=int)
    b = n // a
    i = np.where(a * b == n)[0][-1]
    return a[i], b[i]
```

---

**Original answer**

Below, we write an algorithm that uses a simple factorization for `n`, and a search through all the possible combinations of factors (powerset) but *without repeat*.

First, a factorization that uses the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) (e.g. from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16007256/758174)):

```py
def factors(n):
    while n > 1:
        for i in range(2, n + 1):
            if n % i == 0:
                n //= i
                yield i
                break
```

Then, a modified `powerset` that emits only unique combinations:

```py
from itertools import chain, combinations

def uniq_powerset(iterable):
    """
    Similar to powerset(it) but without repeats.
    
    uniq_powerset([1,1,2]) --> (), (1,), (2,), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 1, 2)"""
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(set(combinations(s, r)) for r in range(len(s)+1))
```

And finally, our function that finds the "squarish root" of `n`:

```py
from math import isqrt

def squarishrt(n):
    p = isqrt(n)
    if p**2 == n:
        return p, p
    bestp = 1
    f = list(factors(n))
    for t in uniq_powerset(f):
        if 2 * len(t) > len(f):
            break
        p = np.prod(t) if t else 1
        q = n // p
        if p > q:
            p, q = q, p
        if p > bestp:
            bestp = p
    return bestp, n // bestp
```

For example:

```py
>>> squarishrt(500)
20, 25
```

You can use this directly to reshape, e.g.:

```py
a = np.arange(500)
b = a.reshape(squarishrt(len(a)))
>>> b.shape
20, 25
```

Note, BTW, that a greedy search through the factors doesn't necessarily yields the best solution. For example:

```py
>>> list(factors(500))
[2, 2, 5, 5, 5]
```

And the best combination of them is `p = 2 * 2 * 5` (first 3 factors) and `q = 5 * 5` (last three).

By contrast:

```py
>>> list(factors(300))
[2, 2, 3, 5, 5]
```

for which the closest-to-square factorization is `p = 3 * 5` and `q = 2 * 2 * 5`.